# Finite non-Hausdorff models of CW-complexes

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology

Years ago, my advisor showed me a construction where you take a CW complex and quotient each open cell to a single point. He said that under certain conditions (I believe always satisfied by the second barycentric subdivision of a complex) the resulting space would be a finite non-Hausdorff space homotopy equivalent to the original space.

**Edit** By 'homotopy equivalent' I really mean they have identical homotopy groups. I don't think this is equivalent to regular homotopy equivalence in the non-Hausdorff case.

He said this was well-known although not very popular. What is the name for this construction? What is a reference for the homotopy equivalence result?

Comment: One name to google for is that of Jonathan Barmak. In particular, he has a Springer LNM on the subject which should be very useful.

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpful too:
http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/finite+topological+space

Comment: What happened to your advisor and why cannot you ask him/her?

Comment: Jim Cannon retired and is composing music and writing a book. He answers e-mails but seems to be enjoying his retirement. He retired to get more time away from school duties and work on things he's behind on.

Comment: Here is an answer by Tom Goodwillie which gives an argument using van Kampen/excision: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28380/a-canonical-and-categorical-construction-for-geometric-realization/28527#28527

Comment: @RicardoAndrade thanks! This answers my question.

Comment: @Brian: You are welcome! I will wait to see if someone gives a better answer to this question over the next few days. If not, I might just write my comment above as an answer to avoid leaving the question unanswered. Does that seem appropriate to you?

Comment: Yes, it does seem appropriate; thanks for avoiding comment blight!

Answer (score 4):

When $K$ is a finite simplicial complex, this was done by Michael C. McCord
''Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces'', Duke Math. J. 33 (1966), 465-474. If $X_K$ denotes the finite space you described, McCord proves that the quotient map $q:K \to X_K$ is a quasifibration in the sense of Dold and Thom, with contractible point-inverses. Thus $q$ is a weak homotopy equivalence and induces isomorphisms in singular homology.

Answer (score 2):

Peter May has been running an REU course on finite topological spaces for a number of years. He has [a bunch of material](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/) up, including a [book in progress](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/FINITEBOOK/).